# Server Side State Management

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I would like to know for a distributed application in ASP.NET MVC, if I have to store global
information that hardly changes, which server-side state management options are preferred out of - Application state, Session state, Database support, Profile properties? I think its Session state and Database support.

Comment: What sort of information is it? if it is global and hardly changes then can you just put it in a relational database table? or, if you are using Azure, Blob Storage or SQL Azure?

Comment: sessions is best option.

Answer (score 2):

This is a question from the MS MVC4 exam dumps, with multiple choice answers :) I'm currently studying for the same... The keywords in question are "global" and "distributed" - so, as far as I understand:

a) Application - is only "global" within the current application thread and won't be synchronized to the rest of the Web-farm, i.e. not "distributed"

b) Session - not valid: restricted to a user = not "global"

c) Database - valid answer

d) Profile - not valid: persisted, but restricted to user = not "global"

This is what the problem is with Microsoft exam questions, it all depends on how you read the question - technically Application state is also a correct answer, because the the data will be global to the application, and the question does not mentioned that the data should be persisted through the forest.

If I have this question come up on the exam tomorrow, I'd say Application and Database, and write down this reasoning in the Notes section. Wish me luck :)

Answer (score 0):

If the information relates only to a specific user you could stored it in Session state / cookies. For example to store users email / address etc.

If you want to cache part of a webpage you can use [Output Caching](http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/controllers-and-routing/improving-performance-with-output-caching-cs)

```
[OutputCache(Duration = 3600)]
```

If you have a single web server you could use Application cache to store some commonly used data / list.

If you have a web farm (multiple servers) you could use something like [ncache](http://www.alachisoft.com/ncache/)

If you are using nHibernate for DB ORM you could use nhibernate 2nd level cache